# Use external library in monaco editor and get transpiled JS

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I'd like to use the monaco editor on a website to demonstrate the use of a TS library that's distributed via npm. Moreover, I like to run the code from the editor inside my website context.

I managed already

- to use the monaco editor, in my case as a react component
- to get the transpiled output via `getTypeScriptWorker` and later `getEmitOutput`

For now my monaco instance handles a singe file. Inside this file I'd like to import another library now.

What I found is the `addExtraLib` method. This is meant to include some `d.ts` definition files in the editor's intellisense. However, only the type definition files will not help me, as I need somehow everything in the outputted JavaScript.

So I know that TS is not a bundler, and maybe that's not even achievable with monaco. Would I then have to use the TS compiler API directly?
I guess I'm not the first one trying to do this and I could not find anything about this on the web.

Does someone know of prior projects doing something like this or have any advice how to do that for me?